# C-map derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

**Problem:**
I'm reading a deep learning paper named [Exponential expressivity in deep neural networks through transient chaos](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05340). I have encountered difficulties in deriving the formula (7) in that paper, it can be regard as a function derivative problem.
Let:$$f = \sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi(u_2)}+\sigma_b^2$$
with:

$$Dz_1={dz_1\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z_1^2\over2}, Dz_2={dz_2\over\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z_2^2\over2}$$
$$u_1=\sqrt{q}z_1, u_2=\sqrt{q}[cz_1+\sqrt{1-c^2}z_2]$$
$z_1,z_2$ are independent standard gaussian variables. How could we get:
$${\partial{f}\over\partial{c}}=q\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi'(u_1)\phi'(u_2)}$$

**Possible useful clues:**

In Supplemental Material, the author hint use chain rule and product rule with indentity:$${\int{DzF(z)z=\int{DzF'(z)}}}$$
which can be obtained by integration by parts.

**My derivation step:**
$$\begin{align}
{\partial{f}\over\partial{c}}=&\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi'(u_2){\partial{u_2}\over\partial{c}}}\\=&\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi'(u_2)[\sqrt{q}z_1-\sqrt{q}c(1-c^2)^{-{1\over2}}z_2]}\\=&\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi'(u_2)z_1}-\sqrt{q}c(1-c^2)^{-{1\over2}}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi'(u_2)z_2}
\end{align}
$$
make $g(z_1)=\int{Dz_2\phi'(u_2)}$, the first double integral in above equation could be writed as: $$\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1\phi(u_1)g(z_1)z_1}$$
Then use the integration by parts mentioned by the paper, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1\phi(u_1)g(z_1)z_1} = &\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1(\phi(u_1)g(z_1))'}\\=&\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1\phi'(u_1)g(z_1)}+\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1\phi(u_1)g'(z_1)}\\=&q\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi'(u_1)\phi'(u_2)}+\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi''(u_2){\partial{u_2}\over{\partial{z_1}}}}
\end{align}
$$
I find the first term match what I want, but there are still two terms left:
$$\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi''(u_2){\partial{u_2}\over{\partial{z_1}}}}-\sqrt{q}c(1-c^2)^{-{1\over2}}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi'(u_2)z_2}
$$
I have no idea what can do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the question myself. The author kindly replied to me and advised a related paper [Deep Information Propagation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01232) to get the detailed derivation. Now I can finally finish my derivation.

**Again** use integration by parts for integration $\int{Dz_2\phi'(u_2)z_2}$, we get:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{q}c(1-c^2)^{-{1\over2}}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1\phi(u_1)Dz_2\phi'(u_2)z_2}=&\sqrt{q}c(1-c^2)^{-{1\over2}}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1\phi(u_1)Dz_2\phi''(u_2){\partial{u_2}\over\partial{z_2}}}\\=&qc\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi''(u_2)}
\end{align}
$$
and the another term left is:
$$\sqrt{q}\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi''(u_2){\partial{u_2}\over{\partial{z_1}}}}=qc\sigma_w^2\int{Dz_1Dz_2\phi(u_1)\phi''(u_2)}
$$
so the last two terms eliminate.